# Count of solutions on "Here's how far we've come together" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10m-questions-milestone

The https://stackoverflow.com/10m page

[image: Enter image]

says Stack Overflow has 10,007,199 questions, but 16,549,092 solutions. How is this possible? Stack Overflow allows one solution for one answer. So the solution count should same as the question count, or lower.

Am I thinking correctly?

I think Stack Overflow needs to change the text "Solutions" to "Answers". Because if a lot of people put wrong answers, then how are those solutions to questions?

Comment: An answer is to a question as solution is to a problem. Questions can have many answers, and problems can have many solutions.

Comment: Please give me your comment with proper format. Sorry I did't get you.

Comment: If I was going to guess "solutions given" is count of [positively scored answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A1). But no, it's just [the count of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa).

Comment: So this content is not good. SO need to change the text 'Solutions' to  `answer`. if lot of peoples put wrong answers, then how's that solution for questions?

Comment: You answer a question, you solve a problem. What is your heuristic for determining what a solution is? Keeping in mind that a problem can have many solutions @Ramesh

Comment: If my answer have 10 Minus Vote, then it's called about solutions or what? @TinyGiant

Comment: A solution can't be unpopular? It would still be a solution if it solved the problem, even if 10 people didn't like it.

Comment: I did't mean by like the answer. I mean  a answer having Minus vote(Some peoples says it's not a solutions). then how's the answer is a solution for a question?

Comment: Some answers that get upvoted do not actually solve the problem, how do you account for that?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Less than 2% of all answers have a negative score. Less than 0.004% have a score as low as -10. It's really an insignificant amount that's not worth worrying over.

Comment: Yes, that's why am talking about it... The solution means only ticked answers. does not all answers.

Comment: That's not what solution means though.

Comment: ***A problem can have many possible solutions.*** The point is that, while it is a good sentiment, you cannot quantify the difference between an answer and a solution at this scale. Thus, the existing wording is just as acceptable as your proposed wording, I see no reason for it to be changed.

Comment: Also, users downvoting a post in no way definitively means that it is not the solution. It can mean countless things, along with "I don't like this post".

Comment: Okay, good!!! So all answers are solutions for the question. if that answer is wrong. But they will take them for a count .

Comment: Actually if i asked a question, then i will go to tick the solution. that's called about solutions( best) other answer's are just answers only not solutions. 

So this content should be look like 

100000.. question

100000... Solutions 

200000.. Answers
.
.

Comment: Why minus votes here?

Comment: There is no way to truly quantify whether an answer *is* a solution using a machine. Not all upvoted answers solve the problem, and not all downvoted answers do not solve the problem. It isn't black and white. A **Problem** is a part of a **question**, they are not one and the same. A problem may be able to be solved in many different ways, just because you (one user) say that that answer worked for you, does not mean that it is the only solution to the problem. It just means that it answered your question.

Comment: okay thanks to open my eyes. :) :) :+1

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, the *purpose* of Stack Overflow is not to answer your question, that is a *side effect*. The purpose is to create a repository of useful solutions to common programming problems for programmers everywhere. That's why we can close questions as duplicates, because the *problem* is the same, so the solutions are the same, even if the question is not the same.

Comment: Hm, an average of 1.65 answers per question seems quite low. Not that I doubt the statistics, I just thought it'd be more.

Comment: @Cerbrus that is also counting unanswered questions

Comment: I know, that's what surprised me, that there's apparently that many unanswered questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus [is:q answer:0 = 1,188,114](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A0) That's roughly 11.87% at the time of this posting.

Comment: I saw another issue in the same screen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303007/spelling-mistake-in-not-a-fan-of-teh-twitters

Comment: @RameshRajendran: I think that one may be intentional.

Comment: okay guys' tell me the count of deleted questions and answers? Is included with `teh`count?

Comment: No, deleted questions and answers are not. Just those searchable.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: no, deleted posts are not included in the counts. There are 2.8 million deleted answers, 2.6 million deleted questions.

Answer (score 15):

All answers posted are (potential) solutions.

Remember that the question asker can only ever select *one* as accepted, but the *other* answers can still be correct and helpful. The question asker could have been wrong even, or simply not have selected any answer as accepted.

And sometimes, just sometimes, a correct answer is unjustly downvoted, and a bad answer unjustly upvoted. Simply counting all answers as solutions without judging is the best approach here. Flagging *Tiz helped me tooz!* posts as *Not an Answer* is more important here than nitpicking over the 'accepted' status or if the answer was downvoted.

Comment: It's misleading (IMO), then, to use the green checkmark graphic next to this statistic.  The green checkmark graphic (AFAICT) signifies an *accepted* answer, not "any answer".