# Spelling mistake in "Not a fan of **teh** twitters?"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10m-questions-milestone

See the content at https://stackoverflow.com/10m, and scroll to the footer of the screen

> Not a fan of **teh** twitters? No problem. Just add #SOreadytohelp to your "About Me" on your profile page.

"Not a fan of **teh** twitters". It should be "the" not "teh", and also you should change "twitters" to "twitter".

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Why Minus vote?

Comment: Probably because that sentence is a joke, intended to be funny. FWIW I didn't downvote. Also, this is a feature request, so people may disagree with your request to remove a joke. #[tag:we-hate-fun]

Comment: _"[@RameshRajendran: I think that one may be intentional.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303002/doubt-about-heres-how-far-weve-come-together#comment236620_303002)"_

Comment: okay, i think the SO content Editor is done him good job

Comment: Minus vote is increasing.  SO will lose there share market price. because may be this question will remove !! It's decrease the question count.

Comment: Actually, "Not a fan of the Twitter" would *also* be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Glorfindel . yes

Comment: @Ramesh *Minus vote is increasing* Read the [discussions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvoting+questions) here ([and on meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+downvoting+questions)) about why downvote behaviour on questions differs from that on the main site. You are right that this leads to the logical inconsistency you signal.

Comment: The question count on the main site is separate from meta. Meta questions do not count in the total question count for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Glorfindel Why misquote? Since "Twitters" is gibberish as well, it's probably some young-person code to make sure that only the "right" people get the T-shirts, the "hpi" and the "in", as opposed to people like myself who are (nearly) old enough to have been the originals of those terms, but weren't. They were programmers.

Comment: @BillWoodger Are you meta-meta-ing us?: *the "hpi"*

Comment: @JanDoggen Sorry, just a pyto...

Comment: *Why downvote?* I think it's probably your use of freehand highlighting. Everyone knows it should be freehand red circles.

Comment: @Glorfindel _Actually_ the sentence would be "Not a fan of the Twitters", plural, which would be correct. Twitter is a noun/adjective ( the short, high sounds that birds make), and you're allowed to not be a fan of multiple twitters ;)

Either way it's obviously a joke.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=teh

Comment: Please stop using code markup for quotations. There is a perfectly good quote markup.

Answer (score 34):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teh):

> Teh is an Internet slang neologism most frequently used as an English article, based on a common typographical error of "the". Teh has subsequently developed grammatical usages distinct from the.[1] It is not common in spoken or written English outside technical or leetspeak circles, but when spoken, it is pronounced /tɛ/ or /tə/.

So it is intended as (humorous) leetspeak.

[There are many more sources](https://www.google.nl/search?q=spelling+the+as+teh).

Assuming that interpretation (see comments below this post) I would deny the feature request.

Comment: Nitpicking, but you can't be _certain_ of the intention. _"Teh"_ _could_ very well be a (unintentional) typo. A well placed one at that.

Comment: Am not a English Man, So it's a Bug from my side. that's all

Comment: Actually, "Not a fan of the Twitter" would also be grammatically incorrect –  Glorfindel

Comment: @Cerbrus Touché. But it fits in with the kind of humor expressed on other parts of the site, so I choose this interpretation.

Comment: Yippee, I was (partially) right on the internet!

Comment: @Cerbrus: You mean "teh interwebz"

Comment: @BoltClock: Teh intertubes, it's all tubes!

Comment: @Deduplicator, [correct, but it is not a big truck.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cZC67wXUTs)

Comment: So StackOverflow uses leetspeak now. Okay.

Answer (score 29):

µ$iÑg "teh twitters" à$ w┌ï┼tεn ì$ $împ└ÿ á ╒ün p└ä¥ σ∩ thè sen┬éncé. ╒úrthεr, ßy ü$ïng thí$ P└a¥ƒu└ ┼ôÑé í┼ @vòíd$ tHë Pò$sib└e ┼ången┼ïä└ çòn√ër$@┬ïò∩ δ╒ réâ$ó∩$ fo┌ dì$└íkïÑg ┼wî┼┼ε┌. φf wHìçh ì wì└└ a└s° avóïD.

> Using "teh twitters" as written is simply a fun play on the sentence. Further, by using this playful tone it avoids the possible tangential conversation of reasons for disliking twitter. Of which I will also avoid.

Comment: 50 1337, 1 4|23 N07 \/\/0|27|-|Y.

Comment: I did not know I read dyslexic.